# Call php function from bash script with array as an argument

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to call a php function from bash script which takes arguments as an array
Here is the code i am trying

```
#!/bin/bash
myArray="'[\"0\",\"adm\",\"passw\",\"passw\",\"passowrdnew\",\"0\",\"Up\"]'"
SN= $(`php -r 'echo set_auth_db(json_decode($myArray));';`)
echo $SN
~
```

I am not getting any output from the script , i dont have much knowledge around php , i am not sure whether this approach is correct.
The function set_auth_db is defined in some other php script which is in different location

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more clarity on:

1. What you are trying to accomplish
2. What the "set_auth_db" function is meant to do and where it is defined

However, just to help you with some of the other issues at hand, here is a modified script that will run and output the data from within the PHP code:

```
#!/bin/bash
myArray="'[\"0\",\"adm\",\"passw\",\"passw\",\"passowrdnew\",\"0\",\"Up\"]'"
SN=$(php -r "var_dump(json_decode($myArray));";)
echo "$SN"
```

**EDIT:** Based on the additional information in your comment, here is a more complete proof of concept:

https://gist.github.com/chrisputnam9/3006ce2035c9dc606c145160d88a6f2c

Comment: this function is defined in some other php file which is in some other location , not where i am running the script and basically i am trying to update a password using this function

Comment: I edited to link you to a Gist with a more complete proof of concept.  You might also consider writing a PHP script that you call directly in the CLI eg. `php script.php` but there are always many ways to treat the cat kindly.